# Can I temporarily install fresh Joomla and connect to old database while I fix it

Tags: database, joomla

My site is messed up and I am trying to fix it, and regardless of it I get help, it is going to take awhile likely, and it's really important that my site be live, even if it's a crappy version with just the articles and no template.

Would it not work to make a backup of the database, install Joomla fresh (the same version) and connect it to that duplicate database (then point my domain there) and then go back to working on fixing the current site that is live now? Are there any issues I should know about going in? There's a good chance the issues are related to the template or extensions (at least my understanding so far, see my other post for details on the issue) so I would think it would be faster to do this to get a working site rather than trying to turn off and on each extension, especially when I have to do it manually (and I don't know how yet) as I can't access the backend.

If this will work, do I choose the database when I install or just install empty and then change what database it connects to or do i install empty and import the tables (and how)? Still have to figure out if I can make a clone of the database and not all the files as it takes hours.

Thanks for the help, and if I should have appended this to the other post I apologize, but I figured its a separate issue.

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have backups of both the files and the database. Then make a local copy of your site where you will work later.

The infection may lie:

1. in the Joomla core files, with extra content (which is usually fairly easy to spot, for example an `eval` of a large base64-encoded variable);
2. in extra files (keep in mind that even images could contain malicious code), these would be usually triggered outside of Joomla for spamming or other nefarious purposes
3. in the database content.

Fix:

1. Apply a fresh Joomla update package over your site; you will only fix n.1 above. This may restore some functionality for the first hour of survival.

Analyse the logs, and try to figure out how they got in. You need to step up security as obviously what you have is not enough.

2. Install a fresh Joomla, add all extensions that your site uses, copy the images folder, then connect it to a copy of the compromised database. This will fix n.1 and 2 above (as you got rid of any extra files). This may survive until they figure out you fixed it; but if you haven't patched your security, they will hack into your site again. Keep a copy of this, and restore as needed as you proceed with the following step.
3. Export the db to sql format (mysqldump or phpmyadmin may come in handy), then search for any xss traces, php code, javascripts that may have been injected. Since a complete control could take days, and assuming the malicious code links elsewhere, look for strings such as "https://" and "http://"; escape `/` as `\/` and `\\\/` to account for json-encoded data as well.

Once the db is clean, your local copy is reasonably safe; update all extensions and Joomla, and use it to restore the website until you fix your security.

Comment: I’m confused. My site is not infected…

Answer (score 0):

It might work, i mean cloning the DB as far as joomla version is the same. It won't break like that, but may fail if files for extensions are not found. This is somewhat wrong, the question is how many extensions you are using and how much cleansing you need.

On the other side you mention that the site should be 'live'. Just do everything on localhost, test, fix templates, etc. Then if you're sure you're done, use akeeba backup and deploy new version to your server without long delays.

Any kind of cleansing needs some start.

1. You can clean the site while live, depends on complexity.
2. Clean might be done offline and deployed.
3. Sometimes import/export custom routines are needed, so you have to make own tools for everything. It occurs with large data, like when people used to made mess inside images folder or something like that.
   4 ...

It's pointless to make copies of DB. You install the same version of Joomla on your local server, then you install the same template, you copy styles etc.
Then you import data with your own tools or paid ones. Estimated time is from few hours to few days, it's just data :)

Comment: If you are able to offer support for Joomla questions, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and contribute there.